# Kettle Change connection used at runtime

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I need, at runtime, to change which connection is used by a **table input** step.

I have 3 connections defined: STG, DWH, DM.
I want to choose at runtime between them.

I can't create a new connection with parameters for server name, database name, etc. I must use the existing connections.

I wish I can write down a variable `${my_connection}` in the box below, but the field cannot be edited.

[image: table input example]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the variable in the connection selector of the Step, use the Host and Database name in the connection configuration.

[image]

EDIT:

You can pass a variable for the KTR to capture and test it using a Switch/Case step that calls a Transformation Executor, in this KTR you'll have your Table input and a copy rows to result step, results which will be captured after the Transformation Executor. You'll need 3 different KTR's, each with the Table input step that's going to execute the row passed by the Switch / Case step.

If i'm not clear or you need further explanation i can perhaps produce an example.

Comment: As I've said, I can't create a new connection with parameters for server name, database name, etc. I must use the existing connections.

Comment: I'd say you're being hindered by this decision, but ok, Kettle has many ways to achieve the same goal. I'll edit my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks. However, using static connections it's not my decision.